# Cron Job Clean Directory

Tags: cron

How is it possible to delete files older than 14 days in a folder using a cron job? Everything I have tried so far hasn't worked.

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to include the things you have tried to i) [show research effort](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ii) so we don't suggest the same things.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that easily enough with `find`. Just run this command in your `crontab` (this will delete files and sub directories):

```
find /path/to/target -mtime +14 -delete
```

From `man find`

```
   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  

   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,

   -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.


   -delete
          Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
          an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit sta‐
          tus will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
          automatically turns on the -depth option.
```

I am not sure if `-delete` is POSIX but if your implementation of find lacks `-delete`, you could also use

```
find /path/to/target -mtime +14 -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: `-delete` is not POSIX. Your two commands are not equivalent though. One will delete directories and the other won't.

Comment: @jordanm yes but since the OP mentioned files, I thought it safer to use plain `rm` for the POSIX solution. I did warn that the first deletes directories as well.